# XPath with RaptureXML not matching nodes

Tags: ios, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse a file in an ePub document using RaptureXML. I can traverse the XML document from child to child but when I try to get the element via XPath, it is not returned.

Here's the XML (container.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<container version="1.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container">    
   <rootfiles>
   <rootfile full-path="content.opf" media-type="application/oebps-package+xml"/>

   </rootfiles>
</container>
```

Here is my parsing code:

```
    NSString *containerPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"META-INF/container.xml"];
    NSData *containerData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:containerPath];
    RXMLElement *containerRoot = [RXMLElement elementFromXMLData:containerData];
    NSLog(@"root %@  ", [containerRoot tag]);
    RXMLElement *rootfiles = [containerRoot child:@"rootfiles"];
    NSLog(@"root %@ ", [rootfiles tag]);
    RXMLElement *rootfile = [rootfiles child:@"rootfile"];
    NSLog(@"root %@ ", [rootfile tag]);
    NSLog(@"attr %@ ", [rootfile attribute:@"full-path"]);

    [containerRoot
            iterateWithRootXPath:@"//rootfile"
                      usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *elem) {
                          NSLog(@"path=%@", [elem attribute:@"full-path"]);
                      }];
/* I've also tried this.... */
    [rootfiles
            iterateWithRootXPath:@"//rootfile"
                      usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *elem) {
                          NSLog(@"path=%@", [elem attribute:@"full-path"]);
                      }];
```

The output for this is:

```
2013-01-14 22:03:43.299 MLReader[9027:c07] root container  
2013-01-14 22:03:43.299 MLReader[9027:c07] root rootfiles 
2013-01-14 22:03:43.300 MLReader[9027:c07] root rootfile 
2013-01-14 22:03:43.300 MLReader[9027:c07] attr content.opf
```

As you can see, when I move through from child to child, I can get to the rootfile element that I am looking for. However, the block in iterateWithRootXPath:usingBlock: is never entered.

I've done plenty of XML/XPath in Java but I am new to Objective-C/iOS.

Comment: This is a problem that I'm dealing with as well. Not sure how to work around it, either. Did you find a solution?